# Sbt helloworld example build is not working

Tags: scala, sbt

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /home/murali/.sbt
[info] Set current project to default-e8cc6f (in build file:/home/murali/)
[error] Not a valid command: new (similar: set)
[error] Not a valid project ID: new
[error] Not a valid configuration: new
[error] Not a valid key: new (similar: name, run, runner)
[error] new
[error]    ^
```

I am getting the above error while i am trying to build scala project using the following command which is suggested by scala helloworld documentation.

```
sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this command:

```
sbt -sbt-version 0.13.15 new sbt/scala-seed.g8
```